# Post new record with ObjectId on Parse platform

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to insert new record into parse platform table with objectId (complaint one).

However when I do POST call:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \ 
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: ${MASTER_KEY}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"objectId": "xdH402yd9z", "field": "testData"}' $URL
```

the post fails with: `{"code":105,"error":"objectId is an invalid field name."}`

How can I insert the record with existing objectId?

Note: the data I'm inserting is basically the same one I got out of parse server prior but with few minor changes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom `objectId` is disabled by default. You will need to enable `customObjectId` on the server. Depending on how you start your server you can try something like below in your app.js:

```js
const api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.PARSE_SERVER_CLOUD || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID || 'myAppId',
  masterKey: process.env.PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY || '',
  //readOnlyMasterKey: process.env.PARSE_SERVER_READ_ONLY_MASTER_KEY,
  encryptionKey: process.env.PARSE_SERVER_ENCRYPTION_KEY,
  objectIdSize: parseInt(process.env.PARSE_SERVER_OBJECT_ID_SIZE) || 10,
  serverURL: process.env.PARSE_SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:' +process.env.PORT + '/parse',
  publicServerURL: process.env.PARSE_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:' +process.env.PORT + '/parse',
  allowCustomObjectId: true, // Here's what you need to enable
```

You can see a complete example here: https://github.com/netreconlab/parse-hipaa/blob/parse-swift/parse/index.js

You can also set the environment variable:

```sh
PARSE_SERVER_ALLOW_CUSTOM_OBJECT_ID = 1
```

Comment: Adding `allowCustomObjectId: true` works!